# Extract hex data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, hex

I want to extract a hex data from a response in JMeter.

I have extract the text value and I want to convert it to hex but I don't know how to do it.
[I want to put the hex data in a variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkUwv.png)
If you have another method to extract hex data in JMeter, I'll take it.

**Edit**

I tried to put on a Beanshell Postprocessor sample :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
vars.put("CHALLENGE",new BigInteger(1, vars.get("CHALLENGE").getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
```

But I have this error :

```
 Static method format( java.lang.String, java.math.BigInteger ) not found in class'java.lang.String'
```

Comment: please update your question to include the code that you have tried so far, and the error/problem you encounter.

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to valide your answer. Thanks man !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Integer.toHexString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int))

> Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 16.

In your case to override (why not use different variable?) variable:

```
vars.put("CHALLENGE", Integer.toHexString(vars.get("CHALLENGE").getBytes()));
```

Comment: It was that ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform conversion using:

- [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [DatatypeConverter class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary(byte[]))

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Hex Conversion]

Comment: I tried your method and it works, but it seems when I extract the binary data with JMeter using Regular Expression Extractor, the binary is not well convert.